# Differential Equation Curve

Tags: calculus

- **Question:**

Determine the cartesian equation of the curve(s).
If you take in a point of this curve the normal of the curve, and you determine the points of intersection
of this perpendicular with the x-axis (the point px) and with the y-axis (the point py), then the point from which you started is the center of px and py. (diff. eq.).

- **My approach gives me "-x²" instead of x².**

$y-0=-\frac{1}{\frac{dy}{dx}}\left(x-0\right)$

$\int \:ydy=-\int \:xdx$

$\frac{y^2}{2}=-\:\frac{x^2}{2}+C$

$y^2=-\:x^2+C_1$

- **My problem is that the answer has to be:**

$y^2=\:x^2+C_1$

Comment: I understand the description now and I believe your equation representation of the scenario is just wrong. Let's find $p_x$ for instance. The normal at $(x_0,y_0)$ on the curve has equation $y-y_0=-m^{-1}(x-x_0)$ where $m$ is the slope of the curve, so $p_x$ will have $x$ coordinate satisfying $-y_0=-m^{-1}(x-x_0)$ so $p_x=(my_0+x_0,0)$. Do this again to find $p_y$, then you'll get your equation.

Comment: Im not sure what happens with the $x_0$ and $y_0$, is it just equal to $0$?

Comment: $(x_0,y_0)$ is any point on the curve. So you'll use the geometric description of the curve to set up a relationship between $x_0,y_0$ and $m$, which will be your differential equation.